# What music app do I install on my new BQ Ubuntu phone? And where to get it from?

Tags: software-installation, music

Subject says it all. What music app do I install on my new BQ Ubuntu phone? And where to get it from? (I'm new to Ubuntu, let alone a smart phone :)

Comment: Haha. I just figured out that there's a built-in music player. Slowly but surely, I'm finding my way in this beautiful phone. :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please post that comment as an answer and accept it as to mark the question solved.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out that there's a built-in music player. Slowly but surely.